# How to add my app to the protocol handler list of chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have Chrome installed and I would want to add my windows store app protocol to the protocol_handler. I want to know if there is any way to do with javascript . I want for every person visiting my page, ask to add my apps protocol to that list and then launch an external app with some arguments. I have searched for 6 hours, found that there is a way to add a protocol handler in Chrome, web+, but this is only for web apps, and does not work for external apps. I tried this but doesn't work:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Iframe test
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="ms-windows-store:PDP?PFN=19185FernandoUrkijoCerced.MyTrip_q1p7rzex4ekjr">Open in "My App"</a>      
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function register() {     
            navigator.registerProtocolHandler("web+myTrip",  "myTrip:place:/%s", "title");
            document.getElementById("iframeTest").src = "myTrip:place:/m/0942y1";
        }
</script>

 <p><input type="button" value="Run ad hoc test"
  onclick="register()">
  <iframe id="iframeTest"/>

</body>
```

This is the list where I want to add my protocol, you can locate on c:\Users|[local user]\AppData\Google\Chrome\UserData|LocalState:

```
 "protocol_handler": {
  "excluded_schemes": {
     "afp": true,          "data": true,          "disk": true,          "disks": true,          "file": true,          "hcp": true,          "javascript": true,          "magnet": false,          "mailto": false,          "ms-help": true,          "ms-windows-store": false,         
     "news": false,          "nntp": true,          "shell": true,          "snews": false,          "unknown": false,          "vbscript": true,          "view-source": true,          "vnd": {
        "ms": {
           "radio": true
        }
     }
  }
```

I only want to insert my protocol

```
 "mytrip": false,
```

If I modify the file manually it works, but I has to be bia Javascript & HTML.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "external apps"? Chrome won't start another app - `registerProtocolHandler` is only designed for web apps. Let your windows store app register its protocol within the OS, this has nothing to do with Chrome.

Comment: Hi, the windows-store-app has an entry there, and because of that, when you navigate to a windows store app page, the store app opens. With Internet Explorer and Firefox there is no problem opening external apps, but it's impossible with chrome

Comment: Do you need to register an OS-level protocol that will open your application from *any* browser (and even Explorer)? MSDN has an article on how to achieve that: [Registering an Application to a URL Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: I need to do that, but I want to post links in a page, and when a user click's it, I want to automatically open my app, I cannot ask the user to follo these instructions.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda: Here is a different MSDN article: [How to handle URI activation (Windows Store apps using JavaScript and HTML)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452686.aspx)

Comment: Hia Cory, thanks for the answer, but I already did that, that's why It works with IE and FF. In fact, if I run from Windows + r, it opens my app. The problem is Chrome, if I paste "myTrip:place:/m/0942y1" in to the URL bar, it search for it instead of executing it.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda: Oh, ok, you never mentioned that it already works in the other browsers. It appears that this is known Chrome bug. See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=162124 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=116452